# Convert string React Component to jsx again

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have one question, because read javascript file from NodeJS and send to the client and here I reveive all file as string (which is obvious) and here is my question. Is any solution to convert string component again to the jsx? This is no only html tags so `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or similar methods don't work.

My string components looks like typical React component, something like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row } from 'react-bootstrap;
import Home from './Home'
     ......
const Index = () => {
   const renderHelloWorld = <h1>Hello World</h1>

   return (
      <div>{renderHelloWorld}</div>
   )
}

export default Index;
```

So this is string I'm struggling with how convert it to jsx (maybe this is impossible) and I should use Server Side Rendering with React methodfs like `ReactDOMServer`?

Comment: May I ask why would you need to pass `.js` file as a plain text file?

Comment: Because user can upload file with code snippet to server and I would like render this file in the client. This is only for dev mode because I use create-react-app and this disable import files outside /src folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, solution for my problem is very popular and simple (in early project stage), to understand problem and fix it we need to go back to the server part of the app. For `React` applications if we want render jsx file from the server, we have to use server side rendering and above problem will be gone. Maybe I show step by step how enable rendering React component in te server.

1. Configure backend to enable the ES6 features

   Install babel packages

   ```
   npm install @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react --save-dev
   ```

   There is many ways to configure Babel, I use the nearest `package.json` for this.

   ```
   {
     ......,
     /*This have to be in the top level in package.json*/

     "babel":{
       "presets":[
         "@babel/preset-env",
         "@babel/preset-react" 
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

More information about babel packages and configurations: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/

2. Send React component to the client

   For this we have to install react and react-dom packages in server side

   ```
   npm install react react-dom
   ```

   For example in your server,js or route.js file:

   ```
    ....  //necesarry imported modules
    import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
    import Index from './Index';

   router.get('/exampleRoute', (req, res) => {

      .... //your route business logic

      res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Index/>))
   })
   ```
3. Render view in the client

   ```
   ...//correct React component
   const[state, setState] = useState({Component: ''});

   fetch('/exampleRoute')
    .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => setState(state => ({...state, Component: data.data));

   ....

   return(
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: state.Component }}></div>
   )
   ```

This is only simple example how you can render React component from backend if this is necasarry. This is not guide for complex server side rendering in application which is more complicated thing, but no difficult thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just plain old JavaScript to do the trick.

```
document.querySelector('#elementToBeReplace').innerHTML = renderHelloWorld;
```

Another Option with react.js is use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: renderHelloWorld }} />
```

Or You can use `html-react-parser`.

```
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

const renderHelloWorld = <h1>Hello World</h1>

<div>{Parser(renderHelloWorld)}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser`.

A utility for converting HTML strings into React components. Avoids the use of dangerouslySetInnerHTML and converts standard HTML elements, attributes and inline styles into their React equivalents.